# how to share cookies value from one server into another server in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

so please can any one tell me, how it is possible to pass Cookies value from 1 server into other server?

it is possible???give me some more information about it.

thanks lot...

Comment: How can we pass cookies to server to server? It is stored in client side right?

Comment: Can you give us more info what do you want to achieve? Are you running an application load balanced (then you mean client side cookies I think) or do you want to achieve something else?

Comment: yes it is stored in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are linked to the domain name. Browser does not pass cookies for one domain to another domain. Said that, it's possible for sub-domains to share cookie if it is linked to parent domain. For example, cookie at `xyz.com` will be sent to `my.xyz.com` and `your.xyz.com`.

In short, if your servers are accessed using the same domain name or sub-domain (of common domain) then cookie can be shared between them.

Comment: how to share cookie sub domain with parent domain.

Comment: @amit, when you create a cookie, you associate with parent domain. For example, if your web site is `my.xyz.com` then you can create the cookie with domain `xyz.com` which would be sent to `xyz.com` and all its sub-domain. In ASP.NET, you can use `HttpCookie.Domain` property to set the cookie's domain (not that browser typically does not allow third party cookies i.e. site at `bar.com` creating cookie for `foo.com`).